# Open txt file in list box in VB using Split

Tags: vb.net, listbox, split, text-files, streamreader

I'm trying to open a txt file in a list box that has information such as:

```
11111\George Baker\825.50
22222\Jane Doe\563.75
```

I'm trying to use the split method, so the data is split up when it's displayed.

I've got it where it displays the data in the list box exactly how it is in the text file, but I can't get it to split correctly and display the information how I want:

```
Number: 11111  Name: George Baker  Balance: 825.50
Number: 22222  Name: Jane Doe  Balance 563.75
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Public Function GetData() As Boolean

    Dim streamer As StreamReader = Nothing
    LastError = String.Empty
    Dim fields() As String

    Try
        streamer = OpenText("C:\----accounts.txt")
        While Not streamer.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = streamer.ReadLine()
            fields = line.Split("\"c)
            number = fields(0)
            name = fields(1)
            balance = fields(2)
        End While
        lstAccounts.Items.Add("Number: " & fields(0).Trim() &
                                         "Name: " & fields(1).Trim() &
                                        "Balance: $" & fields(2).Trim())
        LastError = "File not found"
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        LastError = ex.Message
        Return False
    Finally
        If streamer IsNot Nothing Then streamer.Close()
    End Try

    Return False

End Function
```

This is what I've changed it to.

It's located in an accounts class. I'd like it to load into a list box upon the form loading.

I have imported both System.IO and System.IO.File.

Also, in other examples, I'm seeing a lot of filepaths shortened some directories back using '..\'. It's in the same folder as the solution, is there anyway to shorten that? (also, I didn't include the full filepath in my code I pasted above to save space, it was long...lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the strings you want and append the corresponding positions of the `fields` array (which starts from zero). Here you have a sample code:

```
  While Not streamer.EndOfStream
      Dim line As String = streamer.ReadLine()
      If (line IsNot Nothing) Then
         Dim fields() As String = line.Split("\"c)
         If (fields.Length = 3) Then
            lstAccounts.Items.Add("Number: " & fields(0).Trim() & "Name: " & fields(1).Trim() & "Balance: " & fields(2).Trim())
        End If
     End If
 End While
```

Regarding the path, if it is in the same folder than the executable you might rely on relative paths (e.g., if it is in the same folder, filename; if it is inside a folder, thisfolder\filename, etc.); although this might provoke problems in some situations (relying on absolute paths is always safer). Another option would be getting the directory of the application from a .NET property (e.g., `Environment.CurrentDirectory`).

Comment: When I alter my code to resemble your sample code, it does not show up when I run it.

Comment: I updated with what I changed it to. I also tried what you wrote, and I didn't get any errors, but it just didn't display in the list box.

I moved it to a class to a getdata function and was trying to display it somehow that way. But I'm getting no luck. I am getting an error when I'm trying to use the lstAccounts.Items.Add but I think because it's on the form and not in the class or something?

Comment: Should this be in the form load handler? That's where I have it, along with declaring the streamreader and opening the file. then I have your code.

Comment: @user1368970 this can be anywhere (with access to the controls in the Form); the form load is the quickest option: copy your code (with the corrections in my last update) there, make sure that the file is OK and everything would work fine.

Comment: I didn't get the errors at all yesterday. I only got them today when I rearranged my code. Thank you so much for you help, I will try again!

Comment: @user1368970 No problem. While re-arranging just make sure that the population of the listView is inside the loop and that you can add the listView control without any problem. If you continue having problems, please, be as detailed as possible and will answer you tomorrow.